# Is old Assemblycode still usable?

Tags: assembly

I've found an old book with some assemblycode snippets concerning the old x86 processor.

One of those code-snippets was.:

```
LDA 4567H
ADI A,56H
STA 0567H
```

So I copied that code in such a construct

```
.data
.global main
main:
    LDA 4567H
    ADI A,56H
    STA 0567H
    leave
    ret
```

and received the messages:

- **Error: instruction lda unknown**
- **Error: instruction adi unknown**
- **Error: instruction sta unknown**

So, I'm a bit confused. I always thought, that Intel-Code is compatible to all Intel processors (even the extreme old ones).
Is that correct or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: That's probably 8080 code, which is not compatible with 8086

Comment: The accumulator was named `A` when it was 8 bits wide, `AX` when eXtended to 16 bits, `EAX` with 32 bits, and `RAX` when it turned 64 bit. Assembly code from around 1980 hasn't been much asked for lately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> concerning the old x86 processor

It is not x86 code.  This is from the generation before 8086, the 8080 family.  They were 8-bit processors.

> I always thought, that Intel-Code is compatible to all Intel processors

It was not practical to keep the 8-bit instruction set.  Nevertheless, Intel did make sure that it would be relatively easy to translate 8080 assembly code to 8086.  You could buy a program to take care of that.  Probably best known where [XLT86 from Digital Research](http://www.s100computers.com/Software%20Folder/Assembler%20Collection/Digital%20Research%20XLT86%20Manual.pdf) that ran on CP/M and [Intel's CONV86](http://www.nj7p.info/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/9800642B.pdf) that ran on their MCS-86 development system.  Links to the manuals provided.  Finding a copy and running it is surely going to require a trip to the museum.

Comment: On the other hand: What would you do with 8080 code on a PC? If I understand correctly the `LDA 4567h` instruction would be equal to `MOV AL,[4567h]`. However the address `4567h` has a totally different meaning on an MS-DOS PC than on a 8080-based CPM machine - not even talking about 32-bit OSs...

Comment: Do give the manuals a quick read.  They translate assembly, not machine code.  So it would have said LDA foobar.  Still nothing wrong with 4567h, it is relative from the DS segment register.